# Why does Eevee take so long to render an empty scene?

Tags: rendering, animation, eevee-render-engine, performance

If i open a new instance of Blender with the default cube scene and hit Render Animation, the rendering speed is something in the neighborhood of 2 to 4 frames per second. Even after making the scene entirely empty resulting in a black screen and disabling everything i can see and setting samples to 1, the situation doesn't change much.

I expected a real-time rendering engine like eevee to behave just like one, usually resulting in spikes upwards of 2000+ fps on empty scenes in my system. I was just curious to know why eevee is so glacial by comparison when rendering.

Comment: How did you measure those 2-4 fps? What hardware are you on? On my system Eevee can render several million vert geometry at 60 fps without tanking. You getting single digit fps in an empty scene seems unlikely to me

Comment: @TheBeautifulOrc I merely eyeballed how quickly the frame counter in the top left corner of the render window that pops up changes. I tried on a laptop with a i5-8250u, 16gb ddr4 and SSD (3 fps) and a desktop with i3-9100f, gtx1070, 16gb ddr4 and SSD (4 fps).

Comment: Your GTX1070 is definitely stronger than my old GTX970.
What you should look at is the number displayed by the frame counter. The UI might be updating slower than the actual viewport. Is moving around in your scene smooth for you?

Comment: @TheBeautifulOrc Moving around in the viewport with the "Rendered" viewport shading is perfectly smooth, including playback at 60fps or more. Apparently, i only have the problem when rendering (Ctrl+F12). To be sure i just checked and the "Render Engine" is correctly set to Eevee.